# Why do we write mock objects when writing unit test cases?

Tags: unit-testing

We are currently writing unit test cases in our project . The implementations for database methods exist and is working fine . In this case why do we need to write mock objects ? Is there any specific reason ? Why can't I test the DAO implemntation directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't mock calls to the database because that would defeat the purpose. What you SHOULD mock are, for example, calls to your DAO from, say, a service layer. Mocking allows you to test methods in isolation.

Say you have a restaurant simulation with an architecture like this:

`Cook <=> Server <=> Customer`

You want to test each layer independently. Here the `Server` is your service layer and the `Cook` can be thought of as a DAO. The `Server` is what you want to mock while testing `Customer`, and the `Cook` is what you want to mock while testing the `Server`. The `Cook` unit tests, however, should verify that the implementation is returning a hamburger when a hamburger was ordered and not a rubber tire.

Comment: I disagree with the statement *You shouldn't mock calls to the database because that would defeat the purpose.*  because it seems too generic.  As others say below, you need to unit test everything in isolation.  If the thing you're unit testing is the database access, sure, your comment is correct.  If the thing you are unit testing is not database access, then your first sentence is incorrect.  I agree with everything else you say. +0. :-)

Answer (score 6):

It is perfectly ok to test businesslogic together with the database. 
but these tests are called **integration tests** even if you use nunit or junit or phpunit to execute these.

**Unittests** are spezialized tests where testing in isolation (i.e. buisinesslogic without the database) is important. Mocks/fakes/stups are used to enforce this isolation.

Answer (score 2):

Simply: to test actual DAO and not database content.

Suppose your DAO Person class has a method getByName(). You write a test and call Person.getByName("John Smith"). Suppose the test fails, because somebody removed John's record from database. Now, every CI software and your supervisors/reviewers can claim that your software is faulty, while in reality it is not. If you mock DB, you can prove that your DAO works if it's given correct row from correct table.

If you really want to test database itself, ie: if execution of certain DAO method puts data in a certain state, then it is also possible. What is more it is really helpfull with wacky data models (EAV, nested tree set) where you can't expect database to provide bullet-proof integrity. Have a look at [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason is to avoid the execution time of actually running the database commands.  It may not seem like much but the overhead of setting up and tearing down connections will eventually add up and most likely significantly increase the overall time to run the test suite compared with using mock objects.

Answer (score 0):

To isolate the class you are testing. Or else if the test fails how do you know the problem is in the class you are testing or one of it's dependencies.

Comment: Do u directly call and test methods in DAO implentation ?